# Remove wrapper div from document.createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck on this for the longest time and it's driving me nuts. I've tried a dozen different methods and can't figure out how to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks

Here's my code:

```html
<script>
  function runScript() {
    //get parent of script element
    var element = document.currentScript.parentElement;
    //my html string that needs to be inserted inside the original div
    var item = "<div>test1</div><div>test2</div>";

    //My current method. this method works but creates another wrapper div. I need a way to remove the wrapper div or a different method altogether without any wrapper divs.
    var z = document.createElement('div');
    z.innerHTML = item;
    element.appendChild(z);
  }
</script>


<div id="main-wrapper">
  <script>
    runScript();
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: `element.innerHTML += item;`

Comment: I think you could use `addAdjacentHTML()` or `createDocumentFragment()`.

Comment: @Ele That won't work, since the DIV has two children.

Comment: element.innerHTML = item; <- note that this removes the script after

Comment: @Joey That will remove the existing contents of `element`, he wants to add to it.

Comment: @Ele `<div>Test1</div>` is the first child, `<div>Test2</div>` is the second child.

Comment: @Barmar but if it ran, does it need to run again?

Comment: Any reason why you have a jquery tag but you're not using jquery anywhere in your code?  Are you trying to keep it vanilla and only using jquery as a last resort?

Comment: Just wondering why would you keep the Script tag after it ran @Ele

Comment: @DougF I tagged jquery as a last resort. Looks like there was a simple javascript solution after all. Thanks

Comment: @RandyCasburn Exactly what I needed. I knew there was something I wasn't thinking of. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script>
  function runScript() {
    //get parent of script element
    var element = document.currentScript.parentElement;
    //my html string that needs to be inserted inside the original div
    var item = "<div>test1</div><div>test2</div>";
    element.innerHTML = item;
  }
</script>


<div id="main-wrapper">
  <script>
    runScript();
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. It's funny I was stuck on this for the longest time just needed a fresh look at it. Ended up going with element.innerHTML += item. Works fine for what I need it for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you've tagged with jQuery, you can create the element as follow:

```
$(item);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function runScript() {
    var item = "<div>test1</div><div>test2</div>";
    $(document.currentScript.parentElement).append($(item));
  }
</script>


<div id="main-wrapper">
  <script>
    runScript();
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution as well. Ended up going with the other answer since pure javascript would be my preferred method (for performance). By the way I tried some different variations of this earlier and couldn't get it to work. I knew there was a simple way to do it with jquery. Thanks!

Comment: @RileyBell  no problem my friend!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method.

```html
<script>
  function runScript() {
    //get parent of script element
    var element = document.currentScript.parentElement;
    //my html string that needs to be inserted inside the original div
    var item = "<div>test1</div><div>test2</div>";
    element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);
  }
</script>


<div id="main-wrapper">
  <script>
    runScript();
  </script>
</div>
```

Or use a template instead of a DIV.

```html
<script>
  function runScript() {
    //get parent of script element
    var element = document.currentScript.parentElement;
    //my html string that needs to be inserted inside the original div
    var item = "<div>test1</div><div>test2</div>";

    var z = document.createElement('template');
    z.innerHTML = item;
    element.appendChild(z.content);
  }
</script>


<div id="main-wrapper">
  <script>
    runScript();
  </script>
</div>
```